# <hr> inside container with display flex become corrupted

Tags: css, flexbox

This behavior is a little odd and weird. If there is a container with its `display` property set to `flex` and `flex-direction` to `column`, the orientation of the `<hr>` elements inside it will change and become vertical and its height will decrease to fit the height of the line.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <hr/>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out [this pen](http://codepen.io/ahmadalfy/pen/bEpjyY).

This behavior is confirmed on Firefox and Chrome. I didn't find any explanation for it. How can I fix it?

Comment: putting <hr> inside div or span worked for me

Answer (score 76, accepted):

According to [HTML5 Rendering - The `hr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-hr-element-0), it is expected to be rendered with this style:

```css
hr { color: gray; border-style: inset; border-width: 1px; margin: 0.5em auto; }
```

Specifically, note `margin-left: auto`, `margin-right: auto`.

Those styles are used to center a block element horizontally. According to [Calculating widths and margins - Block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth)

> If both `margin-left` and `margin-right` are `auto`, their used values
>   are equal. This horizontally centers the element with respect to the
>   edges of the containing block.

In a block layout this effect is only noticeable if the block has an explicit width, otherwise the block will grow to cover all its containing block.

In Flexbox it's similar: the default [`align-self: auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-self) and [`align-items: stretch`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property) make flex items grow to cover the flex line in the cross axis (horizontal one in column layout), and [`auto` margins can also be used to center](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins).

However, there is a big difference: according to [Cross Size Determination](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-stretch), `align-self: stretch` does not affect flex items with `auto` margins:

> If a flex item has [`align-self: stretch`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-self), its computed cross size
>   property is `auto`, and neither of its cross-axis margins are `auto`,
>   the used outer cross size is the used cross size of its flex line,
>   clamped according to the item’s min and max cross size properties.
>   Otherwise, the used cross size is the item’s [hypothetical cross
>   size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#hypothetical-cross-size).

Then, you can fix this problem by removing the `auto` margins:

```css
hr {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
hr {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <hr />
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, forcing a certain width through `width` or `min-width` would counteract the shrinking (more technically, the lack of stretch) caused by the `auto` margins.

Comment: That explanation totally makes sense, thank you. I should've referred to the specs first. Now that is a normal behavior, not a browser bug or a problem with the flexbox model.

Comment: @ahmadalfy see if my answer helps. :)

Comment: great answer! However in chrome, the user agent seems to override the `margin: 0;` and nothing happens. Someone has it too? (it's working if I put the style inlined in the html, Am I missing something?)

Answer (score 30):

I found that setting the width of the `<hr>` too `100%` fix the problem. Still odd, I have no idea why this happen.

[Here is a pen](http://codepen.io/ahmadalfy/pen/dGMqPM)

Comment: @ahmedalfy you may like to check answer given below.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. I had hr element as child of flex box element and setting width 100% worked!

Answer (score 6):

Try enclosing your `hr` in another flex-item (like a `div`, `span` or something else) as following. This will resolve your issue.

Reason why this works is all children of a flex box container are flex-items. So in your case `hr` was a flex-item. That's why its styling got effected. When you make this `hr` a grand-child of the flex box container, it will no longer effect its styling.

That's why we added `<div>` as parent of `<hr/>`. `<div>` becomes flex-item of your flex container. `<hr>` is no more a flex-item.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div><hr/></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Further Reading (Highly recommended):

- [Basic Concepts of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)
- [Ordering Flex Items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

Answer (score 0):

I just run your code and in style I changed the width of hr to 100%..
every thing is fine , and hr shown correctly.

```css
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
hr{
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3 id="">Title</h3>
        <hr id="mything" />
        <div class="content">
          <p>This is some content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```