# justify-content property breaking with hr tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If an `hr` element is thrown inside a flex container with `justify-content` set to, say, `flex-start`, the `hr` will ocuppy all the space, and the other elements will be distributed as if `justify-content` was set to `space-between`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34372979/1086511) (from 2015) explains that the left and right margins of `hr` are `auto` by default. However, Firefox's Inspector is showing the Box Model with left and right margins as `0`, as can be seen in the code snippet and image below. When we explicitly set them to `auto`, the Box Model also shows `auto` in these margins.

It seems to be a Firefox bug, since Chrome displays the `auto` margins measured correctly. Or has the specification changed somewhere in the last few years, and my Firefox (Quantum 60.8.0esr 64-bit on Debian 9) is simply outdated?

[image: Box Model in Firefox]

Image showing lateral margins as "0", when they obviously have a different value.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 50%;
}
.div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='div'>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<hr>
<div>C</div>
</div>
```

Below is how it should look (the `hr` has been removed, but it should have the approximate width of the other divs).

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 50%;
}
.div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='div'>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AmareshSM Yes, the `margin` CSS property solved the issue. The strange thing is that my Firefox says that margin is 0, when it obviously isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin: inherit;` will resolve your issue.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 50%;
}
.div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}
hr{
  margin: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class='div'>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<hr>
<div>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but `margin: 1em;` gives a better appearance.

Answer (score 1):

On both Firefox and Chrome, `hr` elements have default left and right margins of `auto`.

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

*Notes:*

*- "inline-start" is the side where text begins. It's the left side in LTR.*

*- "block-start" is the top in horizontal writing mode.*

*- "-end" refers to the opposite sides.*

*- [source: § 6.2. Flow-relative Directions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#logical-directions)*

---

So we've determined that we have a flex item (`hr`) with horizontal `auto` margins.

This means that the `hr` will consume all free space on both sides.

That's why its siblings A and B are pinned to the left, and C is pinned to the right.

This behavior has nothing to do with `justify-content`, which in your layout is having no effect. Why?

> [§ 8.1. Aligning with `auto`
>   margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> If free space is distributed to `auto` margins, the alignment
>   properties will have no effect in that dimension because the margins
>   will have stolen all the free space left over after flexing.

In other words, when `auto` margins are applied, `justify-content` can have no effect because there is no free space left for it to distribute. Hence, `justify-content` is totally ignored in your layout.

---

For your layout to work you need to override browser default styles on the `hr`.

Add this to your code:

```
hr {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```css
.div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 50%;
}

.div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}

hr {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='div'>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <hr>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Or, even simpler, modify your selector from `.div div` to:

```
.div > * {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```css
.div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 50%;
}

.div > * {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='div'>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <hr>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added an image showing how my Firefox shows "0" for lateral margins.

Comment: Firefox here (Quantum 67.0.4) doesn't show 0. It shows the actual length.

Comment: So it was indeed a bug in the old version I'm still using. Thank you.